# URL rewriting - Add default page to domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I want to add defined Controller and Action to basic URL

```
localhost:6473  -> localhost:6473/Beta/Index
```

with the URL rewriting in Web.config but in some reason it doesn't work

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Beta_Local" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(localhost*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern= "^localhost:[0-9]{4}$" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/Beta/Index" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The match url should not contain the domain name, but path. If you want to capture root / you need

```
<match url="^$" />
```

See http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

Also, it seems you don't need additional condition for localhost.

Complete rule could be following

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Beta_Local" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" /> 
      <action type="Redirect" url="/Beta/Index" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

P.S.

If you need to do it in MVC way, you could use routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Beta", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Thank's. It does work. Doing in routing is too late because Routing engine adds Beta and Index as invisible for end user but I want to have exact URL domain/Beta/Index always visible as default (for google analytics)